# Php code in Wordpress title tag

Tags: php, wordpress, title

I've customized my php title tag to change appearance of my site in home page and single posts. My code is:

```
<title><?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') | bloginfo('name') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

It has worked like a charm on single post but on my home page, I can't see "|" character. How to fix it?

Comment: `My code is:` where is your code ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Without specifying the code as code the browser tries to parse it as html. In this case, it tried to parse the title tag.

Comment: When  OP wrote  first, there was no code, he edited after

Comment: you have to `echo` it as you are insinde `php tag`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
bloginfo('description') .'|'. bloginfo('name')
```

The '|' character means OR, if you want to use it as a character, use quotes.

Comment: Even no space between my blogdesc. and blogname, nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

'|' means "logical OR" in PHP

try that. `bloginfo('description'). '|' .bloginfo('name')`

Comment: No help, It is not changed.

Comment: How does this at all improve upon the other answer posted?

Comment: @rnevius, I wrote the answer when there was no answers submitted yet!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in your function.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) :
    function theme_slug_render_title() {
?>
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
endif;
```

Comment: At first, I try this code
`<title><?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description')?> | <?php bloginfo('name') : wp_title(''); ? ></title>`
The "|" would show but It will duplicate my blogname in single post, then I changed into the code I'm facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title), there is a little hack for homepage

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'baw_hack_wp_title_for_home' );
function baw_hack_wp_title_for_home( $title )
{
  if( empty( $title ) && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
    return __( 'Home', 'theme_domain' ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'description' );
  }
  return $title;
}
```

And for inner pages

```
function theme_name_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    global $page, $paged;

    // Add the blog name
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title .= " $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title .= " $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_name_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```